# New to coding, app keeps crashing on start up

Tags: android

I'm trying to have a text field and a text view, and set the text view text to whatever is on the the field.

This is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
            import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView helloMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello); //define textView to show the message

        EditText  nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name); // Text field to get the name from

        String  getName = nameField.getText().toString(); // set a variable with the text field's value

        helloMessage.setText(getName); // set text on the hello textview to be the name.


    }



}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B388FF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/Name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/hello"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any sort of help!

Comment: Post crash logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brother you need to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); before finding any other view

Comment: Harsh is correct, Put the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) right after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

Comment: oh wow what a rookie's mistake, probably accidentally removed it, that solved the crashing issue, yet I have another one with this code, my textView that i'm trying to get the name from the field doesnt show up on the screen, only the editText appears.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` to `onCreate()`